# Call api with https on facebook and foursquare is not working

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, https, foursquare

I have strange problem while working with facebook and foursquare APIs
I can not able to call APIs from my machine through HTTPS,
even i can open facebook with HTTPS and many other site with HTTPS but not 
[api.foursquare.com](https://api.foursquare.com) and [graph.facebook.com](https://graph.facebook.com)

Any help is really appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your SSL certificate isn't validating? Self signed I would imagine since you're calling from localhost?

Comment: I have tried to call API directly from browser, but it not works for me

Comment: @chirag.sweng are you behind a firewall preventing social networks?

Comment: I do curl from my application on both APIs and they suddenly stop working with HTTPS and then i ran same url on browser and it does not response me from there

Comment: No i think firewall is not an issue as i can not able to do this from any where